# Почему qsort не сортирует как надо структуры с динамическим выделением памяти?

Tags: c

Надо сгруппировать все записи по месяцам приобретения от меньшего к большему. Если решать без динамического выделения памяти, то сортирует как и надо от меньшего к большему, но если изменить код, то сортировка не так срабатывает. Ниже код, который сортирует не в том порядке.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define COUNT_ITEMS 4

typedef struct Product {
    char name[256];
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    int cost;
    int count;
} Product;
void printinfo(const Product *prod)
{
    printf("Product name: %s\n", prod->name);
    printf("Date of purchase : %d.%d.%d\n", prod->day, prod->month, prod->year);
    printf("Product price: %d\n", prod->cost);
    printf("Number of products: %d\n", prod->count);
}

Product *prodRead() {
    Product *prod;
    prod = malloc(sizeof(Product));
    printf("Enter name of a Product:\n");
    scanf("%s", &prod->name);
    printf("Enter day, month(number), year of purchase through a space:\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &prod->day, &prod->month, &prod->year);
    printf("Enter cost of product:\n");
    scanf("%d", &prod->cost);
    printf("Enter number of product:\n");
    scanf("%d", &prod->count);
return prod;
}
int compMon(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const Product *partOne = (Product *)a;
    const Product *partTwo = (Product *)b;
    return ((*partOne).month > (*partTwo).month) - ((*partOne).month < (*partTwo).month);
}
int main() {
    Product *prod[COUNT_ITEMS];
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT_ITEMS; i++) {
        prod[i]=prodRead();
        printf("\n");
    }
    qsort(prod, COUNT_ITEMS, sizeof(Product*), compMon);
    printf("Structura POSLE sortirovki \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT_ITEMS; i++) {
        printinfo(prod[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Входные данные(слева) и выходные данные(справа):

```
A                                    C   
10 11 2020                           6 6 2020
1000                                 600
2                                    1
B                                    A
5 5 2019                             10 11 2020
500                                  1000
3                                    2
C                                    D 
6 6 2020                             3 3 2018
600                                  200
1                                    2
D                                    B
3 3 2018                             5 5 2019
200                                  500
2                                    3
```

Comment: У Вас интересное условие в компараторе. Вы точно понимаете, что там написано?

Comment: В компаратор передаются указатели на элементы массива, т.е. `Product**`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В компаратор передаются указатели на элементы массива, т.е. `Product**`, вы же считаете, что там `Product*`.

Попробуйте так:

```
int compMon(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const Product *partOne = *(const Product **)a;
    const Product *partTwo = *(const Product **)b;
    return ((*partOne).month > (*partTwo).month) - ((*partOne).month < (*partTwo).month);
}
```

Готовый код: https://ideone.com/f4ZgE7

Comment: Да, спасибо. Но я немного не понял зачем * перед () - `*(const Product **)a;`, хотя понял, что ** - это указатель на указатель.

Comment: Для того, чтобы привести этот указатель на указатель на Product в указатель на Product.